# C# - .NET 6 - Console app with Generic Host vs without

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I am using the new top-level statements in .NET 6 to create a simple console application, but I don't understand the advantages/disadvantages of using the "Generic Host".
Can you explain?

My code with Generic Host:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

using var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
    {
        services.AddTransient<ITestInterface, TestClass>();
    })
    .Build();

Test();
Console.ReadKey();

void Test()
{
    var testClass = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITestInterface>();
    testClass.TestMethod();
}
```

versus

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<ITestInterface, TestClass>();
var servicesProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

Test();
Console.ReadKey();

void Test()
{
    var testClass = servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<ITestInterface>();
    testClass.TestMethod();
}
```

Comment: Your second example never disposes of the root DI container, so your program could end without cleaning-up properly and may cause you to lose data (e.g. flushing pending writes to disk, especially in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`).

Comment: The generic host rigs up configuration and logging, so it can still be useful. If you only want DI, you don't need the generic host

Comment: @Dai so if I update my code like this, is it more correct? ```using var servicesProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();```

Comment: @Tovich Yes, that's better.

Answer (score 28):

The benefits of using the generic host is that by default a lot of services are already setup for you, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#default-builder-settings).

> The CreateDefaultBuilder method:
>
> - Sets the content root to the path returned by GetCurrentDirectory().
> - Loads host configuration from:
>
>   - Environment variables prefixed with DOTNET_.
>   - Command-line arguments.
> - Loads app configuration from:
>
>   - appsettings.json.
>   - appsettings.{Environment}.json.
>   - Secret Manager when the app runs in the Development environment.
>   - Environment variables.
>   - Command-line arguments.
> - Adds the following logging providers:
>
>   - Console
>   - Debug
>   - EventSource
>   - EventLog (only when running on Windows)
> - Enables scope validation and dependency validation when the environment is Development.
>
> The ConfigureServices method exposes the ability to add services to the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection instance. Later, these services can be made available from dependency injection.

You are not using the generic host correctly. For instance: normally one would add a hosted service so you can use proper DI instead of resolving the required services manually.

An example can be found at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#set-up-a-host)

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

If we extend this example with an implementation of `Worker` that takes in a dependency it will look like this:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<ITestInterface, TestClass>();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}

internal class Worker : IHostedService
{
    public Worker(ITestInterface testClass)
    {
        testClass.Foo();
    }


    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface ITestInterface
{
    void Foo();
}

public class TestClass : ITestInterface
{
    public void Foo()
    {

    }
}
```

Now you see a new instance of `Worker` is created and an instance of `ITestInterface` is injected. There is no need to call `servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<ITestInterface>();` which is an anti-pattern.

**Decision Tree**

- If you don't need all those additional services you can choose not to use the Generic Host like in your second code example in the question.
- If you do want to make use of services like logging, app configuration etc. you should use the Generic Host.

Comment: The Generic host also rigs up configuration and logging, so it can be useful even if someone doesn't want hosted services.

Comment: Correct, there are obviously more advantages. I'll update the answer

Comment: @PeterBons thanks for your answer, but if I don't need a worker (e.g. my console is only to scan a directory on the disk - directory entered by the user, write the result to a file and close the program). Is it still possible to use the Generic Host? And how?

Comment: @Tovich i tihnk what Peter is saying is that "worker" is a generic name, for your operation, aka scan stuff... would then be placed inside StartAsync, Peter please confirm

Comment: @Seabizkit yes, but how can I ```Console.ReadLine()``` inside a "worker"?

Comment: @Tovich why would you want a `Console.Readline()`?

Comment: @PeterBons because I would like to give the possibility to the user to specify a directory to scan.

Comment: @Tovich that does make it more complicated because "Worker"* is not runnning on main thread, and I think to do Console.ReadLine() it has to be on main thread.

Comment: @Seabizkit `Console.ReadLine()` will work fine.

Comment: how to use this with Windows Forms?

Comment: Saying that the topic starter is using the generic host the wrong way is not true. It is more like you can create a hosted service with it. I cannot help having the feeling that the topic starter just wants a simple console application that uses DI and not something that starts running in a different thread. The interface of IHostedService says it all. resolving a single say application class using the DI container and then just plain calling run is just fine for this user.